# Ios/swift / UISearchController or SearchDisplayController with custom cell

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have an app with a search icon / button at the top in the navigation bar.

I'm not sure if it would be possible with storyboard but i would like to display a search controller that appears with a custom table view and a close button, a lot like the wikipedia app

see examples below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUrkE.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ePh4.jpg

So workflow would be:
- Press the search icon, 
- Table view comes up with search focused with a close button
- Search results come in the table view as custom cells from a re-usable source

When I use this search on the wikipedia app it feels very native to ios so I assume there is a way to do it?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a `UITableViewController` object and conform it to protocol `UISearchResultsUpdating`
2. Add the search controller to class

   ```
   let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
   ```
3. Add the following code to viewdidload method

   ```
   self.definesPresentationContext = true
   searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
   searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
   searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
   searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
   ```
4. Implement the following method to conform to `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol

   ```
   func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
   ```
5. On the main page (where you want to show the search button), create a segue to the above tableViewController and set it to present modally when button is tapped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate it, but have I missed something ? Because the search bar doesn't appear on the table view  controller that i made

Comment: self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar this line adds the search bar to your table view. Can you make sure the name of your table view outlet is there instead of self.tableView?

Comment: Worked, looks so good thank you just what I wanted thank you !

Comment: Great.. No problem :)